# How to choose the solvent gradient for the flash column chromatography of a complex mixture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, solvents, chromatography, separation-techniques

When performing a flash column chromatography, it is advised to select an eluent in which the desired compound has an $R_\mathrm{F}$ of about $0.25$ in TLC.

However, if I want to separate and isolate all the compounds present in the mixture, or I do not know which is the desired product, it is advised to use an eluent gradient for the column. But what eluent should be selected to start with? Maybe an eluent in which the compound with the highest $R_\mathrm{F}$ (least polar in direct phase chromatography) has $R_\mathrm{F} = 0.25$? What should I consider when performing such chromatography?

I do a gradient from hexane to ethyl acetate until everything is separated. Is there a more efficient method that saves time and solvents?

Comment: That would be good start since you don't know which product is the desired one. To save time and chemicals, I'd buy an authentic sample and follow through.

Comment: I would do a complete gradient from 100% A to 100% B where A is something non-polar (hexane maybe) and B is something polar (e.g. EtOAc) to ensure I separated everything, and then a final wash with 10% MeOH in EtOAc